# UItextfield adding extra spaces beneath timestamp

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I have a relatively simple comment box (`UITextfield`) for a photo app into which I've found that when entering long comments (usually more than half a dozen words) a lot of blank space appears below the timestamp ("X minutes ago") within the comment box. The longer the post, the more blank space appears within the box. Everything else works fine, the comment is vertically aligned correctly, and the timestamp is directly below this.

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 20.0f, 0.0f, 280.0f, 51.0f)];
    mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundComments.png"]];
    [self addSubview:mainView];

    UIImageView *messageIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconAddComment.png"]];
    messageIcon.frame = CGRectMake( 9.0f, 17.0f, 19.0f, 17.0f);
    [mainView addSubview:messageIcon];

    UIImageView *commentBox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"TextFieldComment.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f)]];
    commentBox.frame = CGRectMake(35.0f, 8.0f, 237.0f, 35.0f);
    [mainView addSubview:commentBox];

commentField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 40.0f, 10.0f, 227.0f, 31.0f)];
commentField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
commentField.placeholder = @"Add a comment";
commentField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
commentField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0f/255.0f green:55.0f/255.0f blue:35.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
commentField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[commentField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:154.0f/255.0f green:146.0f/255.0f blue:138.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"]; 
[mainView addSubview:commentField];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Any particular reason why you prefer a `UITextField` as opposed to a `UITextView` for comments since they could get reasonably long?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the points to do so. Picture something similar to a facebook comment, but beneath the time stamp (yet above the next comment) is a few lines of blank space. It doesn't take much to trigger this (half a dozen words). With regards to why UITextField, I'm actually just teaching myself xcode and this was part of a tutorial template I'm trying to work through. Would using a UITextView address this problem? I'd still be curious as to why it's doing it in the first place. Thank you for taking the time either way! (i've added more of the code if that helps)